# Spss select case by starting character

Tags: string, filtering, spss

I have a data set and i have a variable which contains text, i need to select the cases that do not contain

> RT

at the start. How can i go about doing this? i do not want to compute a new variable just want to set a filter.

I know that i need to use the Select cases -> If condition is satisfied... but i can not figure out what function or formula i can use to achieve this.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT IF CHAR.SUBSTR(UPCASE(MyVar),1,2) NE "RT".
```